# VB: Download ZIP file from internet (and extract)

Tags: vb.net, file, zip

I need to somehow download a ZIP file from the internet using Visual Basic.
Here's what I currently have:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim NewAppData As String
    NewAppData = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%/.minecraft.zip")
    Call DownloadFile("http://blahblahbacksheep.co.cc/.minecraft.zip", NewAppData)
End Sub
```

When I debug the program it gives me the following:

```
Function 'DownloadFile' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.
```

What I'm looking to do is download the ZIP file and then extract it. And if possible, show label's with percentage for example:

```
Downloaded: 100%
Extracting: 35%....
```

Could anyone give me any resources or write up a bit of code to do some/all of this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is really two completely different questions: why do I get a bug when downloading, and how do I extract zip archives. To keep things tidy, and to improve your chance of getting them both answered, they really should be posted as two different questions.

Comment: Sorry, I was getting confused with myself at the same time in all fairness. I also don't want to post too many questions. But thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the unzipping part of your question: [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is a really great, open source, file archiving utility that has a nice command-line interface. Here's an example of how to call 7-Zip from VB (once it's been installed):

```
Set WshShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe " & _
    "a -tzip myarchive.zip file.dat file2.txt file3.png", 1, True
```

This example compresses three files into an archive, while you want to extract files from an archive... just look up the appropriate command for that in the documentation.

Note that a command window will pop up while 7-Zip is executing, and in there you'll see a % progress indicator. If you want this indicator to appear somewhere else, then with a bit of ingenuity you can probably pipe the standard output through to some other relevant location.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any way of extracting the zip without 7-Zip installed?

Comment: Windows XP has no native zip utility. I believe that later versions of Windows may have something, but apparently it's really extremely difficult to use. I remember searching the web for hours and not being satisfied. Anyway, pretty much everyone uses 7-Zip.